# How to compare two Hard drives performance?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

How to compare two HDDs performance on paper?

My ASUS laptop's HDD was making noise so I sent it for replacement to service centre but the new HDD seems slower.

Old HDD: Seagate ST1000LM035-1RK172
New one: HGST HTS541010A9E680

Old one had 128 MB cache with areal density 1Tbit/sq.in and new one has only 8 MB with areal density 694Gbit/sq.in? Which one is better? What other parameters to consider? Laptop is still under warranty

I don't have the Seagate HDD but done the following test on the same HDD in a different machine (little lower specs) and the HGST on my current machine.
benchmark done using Passmark's performance test software.

Seagate's result:
[image: https://imgur.com/YDikWZa]

HGST's result:
[image: https://imgur.com/jHALxve]

Comment: the following tests done using UserBenchmark:-
  Seagate benchmark:-https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgyKp.jpg
  hgst benchmark:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmHvn.png

Answer (score 0):

How to compare two HDDs performance on paper?
First of all, you have to define purpose of use, in relation to which you consider such factors as Speed, Reliability, Price, operating temperature, vibration, support of RAFF, SED...

Which one is better?
On a laptop computer - it does not really matter that much (if you'd compare it with SSD, or, say HDD with 7200 RPM), though i would be a bit tipped off for switching Seagate with Hitachi (as is is less unreliable with non-existent support on our local market), plus it seems to have [a longer write cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).